# Wordpress Visualizer Plugin: Number Format for Data Series in Column Chart only applied in Chart Preview

Tags: wordpress, charts, google-visualization, visualizer

When using Google Charts engine and producing a column chart, the `Chart Settings -> Series Settings -> Number Format` formatter in the chart editor is applied in the `Chart Preview` area in the wp admin panel but is not applied in the final rendered chart in my wp website page when using the following `Manual Configuration`:

```
{
"vAxes": {
          "0": {
            "title": "Notional Advised (bn)", 
            "ticks": [10, 30, 50],
            "titleTextStyle": {"italic": "false"},
            "gridlines": {"color": "light-gray"},
            "maxValue": 50,
            "format": "$#"
          },
          "1": {
            "title": "Clients Advised", 
            "ticks": [10, 30, 50],
            "titleTextStyle": {"italic": "false"},
            "gridlines": {"color": "light-gray"},
            "maxValue": 50
          }
        },
"series": {
          "0": {
            "targetAxisIndex": "0", 
            "color": "#b7d988"
          },
          "1": {
            "targetAxisIndex": "1", 
            "color": "#aedeea"}
        },
"italic": "false", 
"fontName": "Arial",
"fontSize": 16,
"hAxis": {
  "tickColor": "white"}
}
```

I've looked for a manual configuration option to get the series' number formatting back, but haven't come across anything in Google Charts' docs: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#dual-y-charts

Any ideas or workarounds?

NOTE: I've opened this as a potential issue on Visualizer's github repo (https://github.com/Codeinwp/visualizer/issues/542) in case it is a legitimate bug, but hoping for some interim guidance :)

Thanks!

Comment: will you please share the code, at least that renders the chart after preview?

Comment: That's not visible to me as it is wordpress in conjunction with the wordpress plugin, Visualizer, that handles this.